# how to use specific thread execute specific task using threadpool in java

Tags: java, threadpool

I want to use threadpool to execute tasks with different fields. To keep results correct, I have to     use specific thread to execute tasks with specific field. How can I achieve that?

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory , java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor , java.util.concurrent.Executors , take a look at the constructors and static methods to create pools and assign cores.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of ExecutorService to create a thread pool.

```java
ExecutorService executorService = Executors             
       .newFixedThreadPool(Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors());
```

And then create a list of tasks all the tasks will have specific fields.

```java
List<Tasks> tasks; //This will contain all the type of tasks. 
//Tasks should be Runnable or callable depending on what you want
//if you want a return use Callable else Runnable.
```

Pass all these tasks in your executor service execute method.

```java
tasks.forEach(executorService::execute);
```

This might help.

Comment: Thank you. However, I don't think each thread in executorService  executes tasks with specific field.

Comment: Tasks is an object so there will be different Tasks object for e.g. EmployeeTask, now when you create different EmployeeTask objects and put them in a list and pass that list through the executor service each thread will be working on a different object.